# Does the graph have better connectivity if it has larger second smallest eigenvalue of L?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I'm sorry if this question is quite primitive, but I am not a mathematician, who was thrown into a graph theory.

It is stated that: "In spectral graph partition theory, the eigenvector ${_2}$ (also called Fiedler vector) corresponding to the second smallest eigenvalue ${_2}$ (also known as Fiedler eigenvalue, which actually also defines the algebraic connectivity of a graph) of the Laplacian matrix  of a graph ".

However, I was wondering does the larger eigenvalue ${\lambda_2}$ mean that a graph is better connected? Can I compare two distinct graphs with the same amount of vertices, when the second graph is not made from the first one by adding edges, but they both have the same amount of vertices?

I have read a few books and chapters for this matter, but they just state that with addition of edges it does not decrease.

Would be very grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: Hi, the issue (I have) with your question is : How do you define *connectivity* or *better connected* ? One way to do so is actually $\lambda_2$, so the question is redundant. If you are interested by standard vertex-connectivity then $\lambda_2$ is bounded by **above** by the vertex connectivity. There exist also different definition of Laplacian, the standard one (in graph theory) has the disadvantage to induce a dependence between $\lambda_2$ the number of vertices $n$.

Comment: Otherwise **as far as I know**, there are no direct consequences between vertex-connectivity and algebraic connectivity. For instance you **cannot** say for two graph $G$ and $H$ : $\kappa(G)<\kappa(H) \Rightarrow \lambda_2(G) < \lambda_2(H)$.

Comment: Thank you, @PaulHudford for the answer. Yes, I was talking about vertex-connectivity too. However, the other issue I had, is it even possible to compare algebraic connectivity of two graphs, if they have the same amount of vertices: for instance ${λ_1(H)<λ_2(G)}$ and to say that the G has better algebraic connectivity? Or this quality can only be compared between the same class (e.g. path, complete, star, etc) or just of the same graph by addition of edges?

Comment: I guess you meant $\lambda_2(H)<\lambda_2(G)$ ? In this case yes. This is exactly the algebraic connectivity definition. In this case yes, $G$ has better algebraic connectivity, even if $H$ and $G$ are not from same class.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. @PaulHudford, that was very helpful! Thank you very much!